# For which positive integers k is the series convergent?

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{(n!)^2}{(kn)!}$$

What are some main steps I should take to find which positive integers k the series is convergent for?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli it's (kn)!* edited the problem, thanks for checking

Comment: You might try $k=1$,$2$ and possibly $3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** in applying the ratio test, we find that
$$
a_{n+1}/a_n = \frac{(n+1)^2}{(kn+k)(kn+k-1) \cdots (kn+1)}
$$

Comment: how does this help in figuring out values of k?

Comment: You tell me.  What do we do with $a_{n+1}/a_n$ in the ratio test?  How does the outcome depend on $k$?